# Replacing string with fixed beginning and end with PATINDEX

Tags: sql-server, patindex

I am writing a query to find/replace a pattern that has a definite beginning and ending, with wildcards in between.  This is the original URL:

```
  "></title><script src="http://www.weblearn.edu"></script><!--
```

this is the result:

```
  cript src="http://www.weblearn.edu"></script><!--
```

--
this is the desired result:
     (no characters or spaces)

--
How can I replace the whole thing?  Thanks for your help.

```
 SELECT 

 CASE
 WHEN PATINDEX('">%http%<!--', AcademicDishonestyDesc) > 0 THEN 
 STUFF(AcademicDishonestyDesc, PATINDEX('">%http%<!--', AcademicDishonestyDesc), LEN('">%http%<!--'), '')
 END
 FROM AMS_CoursePolicyAcademicDishonesty
 WHERE      PATINDEX('">%http%<!--', AcademicDishonestyDesc) > 0

 GO
```

Comment: You show us the result you're getting now, can you show the result you actually want? (We don't know what "the whole thing" means.) The replacement you seem to be trying to make will lead to invalid HTML.

Comment: Thanks.  I am actually trying to replace this entire string (original URL) with 'nothing,' as these URLs were the result of SQL Injection on our old server.  There is additional data that follows the URL, which I want to preserve.

Comment: Ok, my question remains: can you edit the question to show what you want the string to look like after the replacement (instead of showing what your current query does)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the safest and easiest thing to do - since you've identified the URLs - would simply be to remove the src attribute from any HTML tags:

```
UPDATE dbo.table SET column = REPLACE(column, ' src="http://...bad script..."', '');
```

A quick example:

```
DECLARE @n TABLE (x VARCHAR(255));

INSERT @n(x) VALUES
('...><script src="http://www.weblearn.edu"></script><!--'),  
('......><script src="http://www.weblearn.edu"></script><!--'),
('..><script src="http://www.weblearn.edu"></script><!--'),
('....><script src="somethingelse"></script><!--');

UPDATE @n SET x = REPLACE(x, ' src="http://www.weblearn.edu"', '')
  WHERE x LIKE '% src="http://www.weblearn.edu"%';

SELECT x FROM @n;
```

Results (empty script tags are absolutely fine in HTML):

```
...><script></script><!--
......><script></script><!--    
..><script></script><!--  
....><script src="somethingelse"></script><!--
```

Repeat for each bad script URL. If this is not what you're after, PLEASE update your question with requirements (e.g. show us desired results).